# Reading files from FTP server to DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ftp, ftplib

I would like to load a file from an FTP server into Pandas dataframe without downloading it to disk first.  I have written a script that executes this command but with downloading to disk.
Is this possible in the ftplib library? Do you see any solution to this problem?

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import pandas as pd
ftps = FTP('gssc.esa.int')
ftps.login()
ftps.cwd('/gnss/data/daily/2019/001/')
filename = '19001.V3status'
local_filename = os.path.join(r"C:/path/where/download/files", filename) #example
lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
ftps.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, lf.write)
file = "C:/path/where/download/files/" +filename #example
dataV3status = pd.read_fwf(file,
                           names = ('Mon_ID', 'Full_Mon_ID', 'RNX_Ver.', 'Dly(H)',
                                    'Dly(M)', 'V', 'Receiver_Type', 'Antenna_Type',
                                    'Mkr_Name', 'Marker_Number', 'Typ', 'G', 'R',
                                    'E', 'C', 'J', 'S', 'I', 'MD5_Checksum'), 
                           widths = [5,9,5,5,6,2,20,22,5,10,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,32],
                           header = None,
                           skiprows = 5,
                           skipfooter = 16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with ftplib, you can do something like this:

```
from io import BytesIO

flo = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, flo.write)
flo.seek(0)
pd.read_fwf(flo, ...)
```

---

Though, [`pandas.read_fwf` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) claims that it supports FTP directly.
So this should do too:

```
pd.read_fwf("ftp://gssc.esa.int//gnss/data/daily/2019/001/19001.V3status", ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can stream the file using the package [tentaclio](https://pypi.org/project/tentaclio/)

```
with tentaclio.open("ftp://user:password@host/path/.../19001.V3status") as reader:
    df = pd.read_fwf(reader)
```

Comment: Thank you for recommending this library. I get to know more about it and try this way.