# Reading CSV file downloaded from FTP in Python not reading all rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to read a CSV file from a folder in FTP. The file has 3072 rows. However, when I am running the code, it is not reading all the rows. Certain rows from the bottom are getting missed out.

```
## FTP host name and credentials
ftp = ftplib.FTP('IP', 'username','password')

## Go to the required directory
ftp.cwd("Folder_Name")

names = ftp.nlst()
final_names= [line for line in names if '.csv' in line]

latest_time = None
latest_name = None

#os.chdir(filepath)

for name in final_names:
    
    time1 = ftp.sendcmd("MDTM " + name)
    if (latest_time is None) or (time1 > latest_time):
        latest_name = name
        latest_time = time1

file = open(latest_name, 'wb')

ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ latest_name, file.write)

dat = pd.read_csv(latest_name)
```

The CSV file to be read from FTP is as given below-

[image]

The output from the code is as-

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead, post the text itself, [formatted in a code-block](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you close the file, before you try to read it, using `file.close()`, or even better using `with`:

```
with open(latest_name, 'wb') as file:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ latest_name, file.write)

dat = pd.read_csv(latest_name)
```

---

If you do not need to actually store the file to local file system, and the file is not too large, you can download it to memory only:
[Reading files from FTP server to DataFrame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67632631/850848#67632878)

---

Though, [`pandas.read_csv` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) claims that it supports FTP directly.
So this should do too:

```
pd.read_csv("ftp://username:password@example.com/remote/path/" + latest_name)
```