# Use CSV data downloaded from ftp with csv.reader

Tags: python, csv, ftp

I'm working on a little script that downloads a csv file from a ftp server, and when downloaded i want to do some calulations on each row before i write it to a new file.

i have the ftp part working, but i cant figure out how to use the BytesIO data as csv data.

Im using the code below but that prints 0 rows.

Any help or push in the right direction would be very appreciated.

```
from ftplib import FTP
import io

ftp = FTP(FTP_SERVER)
ftp.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASSWORD)
csv_data = io.BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + FTP_FILE, csv_data.write)

csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=",")
for row in csv_reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Try: https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/ instead.

Comment: Thanks @alvas! I'll have a look at that, but i rather not use any external modules if possible. Any way i can get this working without it!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. After the download, the read/write pointer of the `BytesIO` is at the end. You have to seek it back to the beginning before you read it.
2. Additionally, you need to convert the downloaded bytes to text.

```
csv_data.seek(0)
csv_data = io.TextIOWrapper(csv_data, encoding='utf-8')
```

---

See also [Read CSV files to Pandas dataframe from FTP with Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73984577/850848).

Comment: Thanks! I thought that too and tried that but that results in the error: "_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: Did you try `StringIO` instead of `BytesIO`?

Comment: I did but that cant be passed to ftp.retrbinary()

Comment: Oh man, i tried both of those, just not together! Thanks so much for helping me out here... this was driving me mad! But my script is working like a charm now! :)